# как реализовать слайдер (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Всем привет. Верстаю шаблон и тут задался вопросом, как реализовать данный слайдер.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно блок цельный, фон во всю ширину. И в нем же : Лого + Заголовок и p-шка + кнопка. 
Шаблон не заказной, верстаю для самообучения.

Comment: написать простой слайдер в bootstrap на всю ширину ?? я правильно понял?

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите стандартную [карусель bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/).

Убери стрелки и кастомизируй индикаторы.

Comment: не получилось, текст не хочет быть внутри картинки, он постоянно прыгает под нее

Comment: @lausa что не получилось? каковы были ваши попытки? добавьте код ваших попыток прямо в ваш вопрос